# Gatsby build fails because window is undefined in a React hook

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a custom hook which checks the window width to conditionally render some UI elements. It works ok during development, but fails on Gatsby build.

Here is the code for my hook:

```
export const useViewport = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize);
  }, []);

  // Return the width so we can use it in our components
  return { width };
}
```

Then in my component I use it like this:

```
const { width } = useViewport();
const breakpoint = 767

/** in JSX **/

{
  width > breakpoint ? <Menu {...props} /> : <Drawer {...props} />
}
```

According to Gatsby [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/) `window` is not available during the build process. I've tried to `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` condition to the hook, but I get the following error:

```
Cannot destructure property 'width' of 'Object(...)(.  ..)' as it is undefined
```

I've also tried to wrap `const { width } = useViewport()` in `React.useEffect` hook, but then I get an error that `width` in my JSX is undefined.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See few [solutions here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/12427#issuecomment-477812135)

Specially this one:

> You'd need to adjust the hook itself. Defining default values in the outside scope and using them as default state should do the trick:

Comment: Sadly, this solution causes an "Invalid hook call" error. If applicable, the best solution is to use CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523091/react-gatsby-render-different-component-based-on-screen-size/64567847#64567847

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but saw this whilst searching for something else.
Window is not avaliable during SSR/SSG so you need to wrap any usage of `window` in an iffy.

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // Do what you need with any calls to window
}
```