# React / Gatsby - render different component based on screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

(Heads-up warning: I am not extremely familiar with React/GraphQL, so please go easy on me).

I am building a blog using Gatsby and my navbar changes its appearance based on the screen-size. In the middle of my navbar is the logo of the blog. Now, when the reader is viewing the page on Desktop, I want the full logo (including text) to show. When they are viewing it on mobile, I only want the actual logo (excluding text) to be rendered (I have one image with the full logo and one image with the shortened logo).

So far, my approach has been to 1. create two separate SiteNavLogo-components and 2. check the current window size using the following block of code (I removed all of the code that is not relevant to this problem and replaced it with "...") and 3. render one of the two logo-components conditionally:

```
class SiteNav extends React.Component {
  ...
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    changeLogo = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches;
    return (
      <>
            ...
            {changeLogo && (
            <SiteNavLogoMobile />) || !changeLogo &&
            <SiteNavLogo/>}
      </>
    );
 }
}
```

This works fine with `gatsby develop` but fails with `gatsby build` because "window" is not available. In [this](https://medium.com/@raravi/gatsby-and-the-window-variable-352ed558a8c0#:%7E:text=During%20build%2C%20Gatsby%20compiles%20your,hence%20window%20is%20not%20accessible.) article I found the recommendation to use componentDidMount, so I tried this:

```
class SiteNav extends React.Component {
   changeLogo = false;
   componentDidMount(): void {
    this.changeLogo = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches;
  }
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <>
            ...
            {this.changeLogo && (
            <SiteNavLogoMobile />) || !this.changeLogo &&
            <SiteNavLogo/>}
      </>
    );
 }
}
```

The problem with this is that the first render cycle is executed before componentDidMount is executed, which means that the page will always be rendered with changeLogo=false.

How can I make it so that when a mobile user views the page, the shortened logo is rendered? (Do I even need two components for this or can I just change my GraphQL-query?)
Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't handle this with JS, as it'll always cause rendering mismatch.

For example, if by default, you render `<Logo>` when the viewport width is smaller than 400px, but a user visit your site with a viewport width of 600px, they will see a brief flash of wrong component before React kicks in.

You could get around this by checking `window` and just render nothing in SSR (which is a fine approach for non-SEO sensitive content), but then you lose out on benefit of using Gatsby in the first place, search engine can't see your logo, and depend on the way your layout is setup, user might still see a flash of layout shift.

If your component can't be simply modified with only CSS, what I recommend is the good ol' CSS switcharoo:

```
<div className="display-xs">
  <MobileVariant />
</div>

<div className="display-md">
  <DesktopVariant />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tested it out and it does indeed flash. Now that I changed it using CSS it no longer flashes briefly. Without your comment, I probably would not have noticed it; thank you very much for bringing this up!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return (
  <>
        ...
        { typeof window !== 'undefined' 
          ? window.innerWidth <= 400 ? <SiteNavLogoMobile /> : <SiteNavLogo/> 
          : null
        }
  </>
);
```

Of course, this code should be refactored to avoid chained ternary conditions (bad readability) but I wanted to show the idea of the approach. If the `window` is defined, it will match the first condition, rendering one component or another depending on the `innerWidth` (you can change it to your `matchMedia`) if not, it will not render anything (`null`) until the code gets the `innerWidth` of the window.

You can add it to a custom function instead of rendering it in the JSX, as you wish.

This code will be triggered as the window width changes.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really minimal solution and it worked perfectly. I really like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the component's state to store the `changeLogo` variable. By using a state variable, `changeLogo` is correctly updated in `componentDidMount()` resulting in the correct nav bar being displayed.

To ensure that `changeLogo` updates depending on the viewport width, an `addEventListener` has also been included in the component.

```
class SiteNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      changeLogo: false
    };
    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
  }

  handleResize() {
    this.setState({
      changeLogo: window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)").matches
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.changeLogo && <SiteNavLogoMobile />}
        {!this.state.changeLogo && <SiteNavLogo/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-meadow-1kjym?file=/src/Nav.js) demo.

Comment: But this only renders it onces instead of listening to the viewport width?

Comment: It wasn't clear in your question that you wanted it to listen to the viewport width. I've updated the answer above to allow for this.

Comment: Thank you for this! This approach makes perfect sense to me, but for some weird reason `handleResize()` does not get executed. I probably just made some minor error that prevents the function from executing. I will definitely keep the logic with the state in mind for the future! This does seem quite useful.